# Using Regular Expression to narrow down dictionary based on Wordle rules

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to do Wordle Solver as my resume project. I want to develop some word suggestions by narrowing down dictionary of words using RegEx.

Is it possible to write RegEx such that it searches for words in the dictionary that satisfy these 3 conditions?

1. Word that starts with the letter 'C'
2. does not contain letter 'T' anywhere in the word
3. The word overall must contain letter 'E' somewhere but not a first(word starts with 'C') and third positions?

My attempt is below but I'm failing with the 3rd requirement.

```
[c][^\Wt][^\Wte][^\Wt][^\Wt]
```

Comment: do you look for a solution in general or does it have to be regex? since wordle are always fixed length 5 letters words I think it is easier to filter just by defining the rules by indexing their positions directly

Comment: I look for a solution in general. What do you mean indexing their positions directly? I would appreciate an example. Btw, as for RegEx, my best and not at all elegant solution so far is (?=.*t)(?=.*e)(?=.*a)(?=.*l)(?!psyhei)\w{5}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below assumes you use flags to enable case insensitivity and multiline mode (so `^` matches the beginning of a line and `$` the end) - `re.I` and `re.M`.

> Word that starts with the letter 'C'

This is just `^C.*$`

> Does not contain letter 'T' anywhere in the word

This can be accomplished with the positive lookahead `(?=^[^T]*$)`

> The word overall must contain letter 'E' somewhere but not a first and third positions

This is a bit tricker, but doable:

- assure the text contains an `E` somewhere `(?=.*E)`
- assure an `E` is not in the third position `(?!^..E)`

Gluing it all together (and pulling the `^`'s out front):

```
^(?=[^T]*$)(?=.*E)(?!..E)C.*$
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just an example. You could do some little helper functions to make it more flexible. functions like "letter isn't in the word at all", "specific letter at 3rd position" ....

```
dic = {'words': ['value', 'cache', 'cacao', 'racer', 'house']}

filt = [x for x in dic['words'] if all([x[0].upper()=='C', 'T' not in x.upper(), 'E' in x.upper()])]

print(filt)
['cache']
```

List comprehension with if condition. all conditions are wrapped in `all()` which only returns `True` if every single statements is `True`

Comment: I've never seen list comprehension with if condition. I saw them only separate. Thank you for introducing me to them. This is actually a great solution, thanks again. P.S. Just out of curiosity, if anyone knows how to do the same in RegEx, I would like to know. Since I spent time on it, it would be interesting to find out :)

Comment: I couldn't manage to make this solution work. The reason is that I need to change conditions with the new information that I receive. And this way of coding it does not allow to do that. Will look into RegEx again.

Comment: Don't understand where you stuck. The answer with regex works totally fine, still whatever solution you prefer you need to adjust those rules everytime somehow. If you are interested, update your question with some code how your current three rules appear, maybe we find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can just get the Wordle dictionary from here:

https://static.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2022/01/25/wordle-solver/assets/solutions.txt